# How to calculate resistor values for CFO differential amplifier Op-Amps?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analysis, differential

I know that resistor calculations for current feedback amplifiers is different from their voltage feedback counterparts ( especially in higher frequencies as they have small impedance in inverting input buffer and the feedback resistor should be selected small to avoid impact of stray capacitance). That's why for CFOs one should mostly rely on recommended resistor values in their datasheets.

But in most datasheets, the resistor values are based just on inverting/non-inverting amplifiers and not differential amplifiers [(As for AD811)](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD811.pdf&ei=ZPReUornJoffsga9-4GADQ&usg=AFQjCNGC4IL6zbI9Ra7p0uuL5bRrFLG6fw&sig2=clTQvqw2ETNAvQEZ98k4dg&bvm=bv.54176721,d.Yms). Although I have seen the following formula for arbitrary resistor selection, it is just based on inverting/non-inverting amps and performance is not guaranteed :

***Is there any formula/ method like that for resistor value selection in CFO differential op-amps? (except trial and errors!):***

[image]

ZB= input buffer impedance,ZF1,ZG1: for gain=1 ; ZFN,ZGN=new desired value

[image]

[image]

For R2/R1=R4/R3:

[image]

Comment: There is the added problem that, for normal voltage feedback diff amps, the impedance seen by one leg of the signal is not the same as the other leg if the resistor values are matched like above. Good question though.

Comment: @Andyaka I had not noticed this problem. I think this may bring a good hint to the answer of the question. If you kindly look at my other post (the link below) , in that schematic inputs have no resistance to w1/w2 ( they may see the output impedance of AD834 that is not in the datasheet but assumed euqual) but the circuit works fine. I am working on this hint and hope that leads to a result.http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/85572/question-about-ad834-ad811-as-voltage-controlled-amplifier

Comment: It's only a problem when your signal may not like to have unequal impedances to earth/gnd. This is not the case on the AD534 multiplier circuit.